# shuffle objectindex in nsmutable Array objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to shuffle my whole ObjectIndex in NSMutableArray.

For example, if my JSON should be like this:

```
[{@"name":@"Vikas" , @"Id":@"1",@"subject":@"english"},
{@"Name":@"Rajat",@"Id":@"2",@"Subject":@"Math"},
{@"Name":@"Jhon",@"id":@"3",@"Science"}]
```

I want result should be like this:

```
[{@"Name":@"Jhon",@"id":@"3",@"Science"},
{@"Name":@"Rajat",@"Id":@"2",@"Subject":@"Math"},
{@"name":@"Vikas" , @"Id":@"1",@"subject":@"english"}]
```

I want to shuffle whole object but I am unable to do this in Objective-C.

```
- (void)shuffle
{
    NSUInteger count = [self count];
    if (count <= 1) return;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i) {
        NSInteger remainingCount = count - i;
        NSInteger exchangeIndex = i + arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t )remainingCount);
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:exchangeIndex];
    }
}
```

This is my code. I don't know where I was wrong. If someone knows then please tell me.

Comment: i want suffel my whole objectindex to  another objectindex  . please help me thanks

Comment: your code has self count. this means you have a category or custom class for the nsmutablearray that you store the json objects. show more code how u created the array in your project. and how u load it from json.

Answer (score 0):

Create category on NSMutableArray:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (Shuffle)
- (void)shuffle;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffle)
- (void)shuffle {
    for (NSInteger i = self.count-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((uint32_t)i+1)];
    }
}
@end
```

Shuffle your mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *t = [@[@{@"Name":@"Vikas", @"Id":@"1", @"Subject":@"English"},
                      @{@"Name":@"Rajat", @"Id":@"2", @"Subject":@"Math"},
                      @{@"Name":@"John", @"Id":@"3", @"Subject":@"Science"}] mutableCopy];
[t shuffle];
```

Answer (score -2):

We have exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex: already exists. Make best utilization of it and write logic on top in the way you want to exchange.